# How do chained functions get executed as goroutines?

Tags: go, goroutine

Given [this playground](http://play.golang.org/p/dI4q1Y8FzX):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    go oneFunc().anotherFunc()
}

func oneFunc() something {
    fmt.Println("oneFunc")
    return something{}
}

type something struct{}

func (s something) anotherFunc() {
    fmt.Println("anotherFunc")
}
```

Why is the output:

> oneFunc

and "anotherFunc" is never printed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`anotherFunc` doesn't execute until `oneFunc` returns a value. Because of this, the program exits before `anotherFunc` is able to run. You need to wait for `anotherFunc` to run before `main` exits.

You can do this via Go channels. **For Example:**

http://play.golang.org/p/dWoLB9afSj

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go oneFunc(ch).anotherFunc()
    fmt.Println("Waiting...")
    <-ch
    fmt.Println("Done.")
}

func oneFunc(ch chan int) something {
    fmt.Println("oneFunc")
    return something{ch}
}

type something struct{
    ch chan int
}

func (s something) anotherFunc() {
    fmt.Println("anotherFunc")
    s.ch <- 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The expression behind the `go` keyword is evaluated and the function value of that expression is then executed concurrently.

So, in your example `oneFunc()` is called, hence the `oneFunc` output, and the method `anotherFunc` on the returned instance is called concurrently. 
However, your program terminates before the goroutine can run which
is why you don't see `anotherFunc` printed.

Solution: Use [`sync.WaitGroup`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) or channels for synchronization.

To actually (empirically) verify that your `go` call executes `anotherFunc` concurrently
and **not** `oneFunc` you can print the stack in each function and compare the output.
Example ([on play](http://play.golang.org/p/9tzV2sj8G6)):

```
var wg = sync.WaitGroup{}

func main() {
    wg.Add(1)
    go oneFunc().anotherFunc()
    wg.Wait()
}

func oneFunc() something {
    fmt.Println("oneFunc")

    buf := make([]byte, 4096)
    runtime.Stack(buf, false)
    fmt.Println("Stack of oneFunc:", string(buf))

    return something{}
}

type something struct{}

func (s something) anotherFunc() {
    defer wg.Done()

    buf := make([]byte, 4096)
    runtime.Stack(buf, false)
    fmt.Println("Stack of anotherFunc:", string(buf))

    fmt.Println("anotherFunc")
}
```

You will see something like this:

```
oneFunc
Stack of oneFunc: goroutine 1 [running]:
main.oneFunc()
    /tmpfs/gosandbox-342f581d_b6e8aa8b_334a0f88_c8221b7e_20882985/prog.go:20 +0x118
main.main()
    /tmpfs/gosandbox-342f581d_b6e8aa8b_334a0f88_c8221b7e_20882985/prog.go:11 +0x50

Stack of anotherFunc: goroutine 2 [running]:
main.something.anotherFunc()
    /tmpfs/gosandbox-342f581d_b6e8aa8b_334a0f88_c8221b7e_20882985/prog.go:32 +0xb2
created by main.main
    /tmpfs/gosandbox-342f581d_b6e8aa8b_334a0f88_c8221b7e_20882985/prog.go:11 +0x69

anotherFunc
```

The stack trace even tells you that the two functions are running in different 
goroutines, no comparison of method calls needed.

Answer (score 2):

The way that I like to about it is this, `go` – like `defer` – consumes the *last* invocation, or pair parentheses, on the line and will invoke that function *out of order*. Every invocation before that is synchronous.

Where `go` makes the invocation concurrent. And `defer` delays invocation until current function returns.

There is a really good example of this in the [`defer` section](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#defer) of [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html)

Comment: Albeit you've shared a very useful link to Effective Go, your answer is not giving an explanation of behavior described in question.